# Why is Duration defined as a separate type in schema.org?

Tags: schema.org

According to http://schema.org/Recipe I can define a `cookTime` value as a `Duration` type.

Now [Duration](http://schema.org/Duration) is defined as its own type but the [Recipe](http://schema.org/Recipe) specifies it should be an ISO 8601 format string.

Why have the `Duration` type if it should be text? I couldn't find any good explanations for this. Is the schema.org type hierarchy broken?

Answer (score 1):

Duration, like the other quantities, are just strings. You don't use `itemscope itemtype="…"` with them, you just put a string in that format. The ‘type’ is used to indicate the required string format. There are no properties of Duration itself.

For example, a cookTime of 1h using the Duration type is:

```
<meta itemprop="cookTime" content="PT1H">
```

Notice the lack of itemscope and no declaration of the Duration type. This meets the Duration type though, because the string is of the correct format.

Another example would be [Distance](http://schema.org/Distance).

> Properties that take Distances as values are of the form ' '. E.g., '7 ft'.

This isn't a type like you'd usually think of a type, with properties and such. This is just a string, with a format required to meet the type.